# If custom module not active it not render default magento block - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

I have module overwrite **Magento/Theme/Block/Html/Topmenu**.

i want check if My module is active render **myBlock and customTopmenu.phtml** else render default.

This code in myBlock file.

```
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Html; 

 use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
 use \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
 use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

 class Topmenu  extends Template 
 {
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        ...
        array $data =[]
    ){
        ...
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }   

    protected function _toHtml()
    {       
        $this->setModuleName('Magento_Theme');
        // check Custom_Module is acitve
        if($this->getActive()){
            $this->setTemplate('Custom_Module::html/topmenu.phtml');
        }       
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
 }
```

**Added**
this is content di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference  for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Custom\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
    <type name="Custom\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">custom-top-menu</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Now i get issue when Custom_Module not active it not render default.

Any help or any suggestion diff for my question is appreciated.

i checked. When My Module not checked 
template is `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml` and Block is `Custom\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu`. How to change Block to `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking in block file you could use it in layout xml file

```
<referenceBlock name="store.menu">
 <block class="Custom\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ifconfig="section_id/group_id/field_id" before="-"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Where section id , group id and field id will be the backend config setting i suppose that you have used in your custom module system.xml. You can find the store.menu on below path `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

Comment: I tried It but not work.

Comment: Did you override topmenu properly, are you sure it is not conflicting with any changes. Possibly you could check your log because layout xml file should work in placing of  blocks

Comment: I added file di.xml in my question.

Comment: Did you tried removing your _tohtml code and just using the preference in di.xml, Because setting template with ifconfig should work.

Comment: I fixed.  I use  `Custom\Module\Block\Html\Tophtml extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`